# Create a button that goes to another class in Swift

Tags: swift, class, button

I have a button that I programmatically created. I want to it to execute the methods in another class when pressed, programmatically. This is part of my horizontal scroll view code.

```
 let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
 button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "bell.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
 horizontalScrollView.addItem(button1)
```

I want button1 one to open another class and execute methods in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform any method on action in another class, you have to use protocol.

//Outside 1st class

```
protocol abc {
     func xyz()
}
```

//Inside 1st class

```
var delegate: abc?
```

//Inside 1st class on action

```
self.delegate.xyz()
```

//Inside 2nd class you want to perform method

```
extension 2nd: abc {
    func xyz(){
      //code 
   }
}
```

//Inside 2nd class where the instantiate process is performed

```
let obj = 2nd initialiser
obj.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps.